# Many to many outer join clause

Tags: sql

This is my database schema:

user

```
| id | firstName |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | Adam      |
| 2  | Bob       |
```

permission

```
| id | title |
|----|-------|
| 1  | Foo   |
| 2  | Bar   |
| 3  | XYZ   |
| 4  | ABC   |
```

user_permissions

```
| user_id | permission_id |
|---------|---------------|
| 1       | 1             |
| 1       | 2             |
| 2       | 1             |
```

I want to check which permissions the user with `id = 1` has and which he doesn't. I tried with this:

```
select up.permission_id, up.user_id 
from permission a 
right outer join user_permissions up on a.id = up.permission_id 
right outer join user u on u.id = up.user_id  
where u.id = 1
```

but I got:

```
| permission_id | user_id |
|---------------|---------|
| 1             | 1       |
| 2             | 1       |
```

and what I want to get is:

```
| permission_id | user_id |
|---------------|---------|
| 1             | 1       |
| 2             | 1       |
| 3             | NULL    |
| 4             | NULL    |
```

Any ideas whats wrong there?

Comment: Make the  `u.id = 1` condition part of the  `ON` clause. When it is in `WHERE` it excludes `null`s.

Comment: You even do not need to join `user` table in this case. It should be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get all available permissions and your `WHERE` clause should be removed, it should be used in `LEFT OUTER JOIN user_permissions up ON a.id = up.permission_id AND up.user_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause states that `where u.id = 1`, which will filter away the wanted results. you can add an or clause or coalesce function. `where u.id = 1 or u.id is null` or with coalesce `where coalesce(u.id, 1) = 1`. (Coalesce returns the value in second parameter if first parameter is null.)

Comment: `NVL` .. Note OP hasn't tagged the question with `oracle`.

Comment: good point, changed my answer to `coalesce` which is used more across different databases

Comment: Is there any reason to use `coalesce` instead of `AND up.user_id = 1` in `ON` clause?

Comment: @dafie No, both will work, as long as you remove the `WHERE` clause you can use that in the ´ON´ clause.